# Using word[1:2] instead of just word[1]?

Tags: python, string, slice

I came across an example in a Python textbook that used `word[1:2]` to slice a string. It was doing it this way to demonstrate that only one letter of the string would be sliced.

It got me thinking - is there ever a use case where one would use `word[1:2]` instead of just `word[1]`, which returns the same result?

Comment: Didn't you ask this [once already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61734017/3001761)? They're **not** the same result, in general. Indeed given that you seem to have moved from a list to a string, this is likely exactly the thing the textbook is trying to teach you.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel They are not. One will raise an IndexError while the other won't. Also, if `word` would have been a list, then one would return a list while the other won't

Comment: Sorry, I removed my first comment. I wanted to say they are the same when slicing string with len(string)>1 but not when slicing list. For string string[N] == string[N:N+1], this is not the case with list, as list  returns N_value for list_[N], while a list with a value_N when list_[N:N+1] namely  [N]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unwritten rule is that slicing will return a *sub-sequence* and subscription will return an *element*. It just happens that for length one strings, these notions are equal. But there is a subtle API difference: slicing strings can not throw an `IndexError`

```
>>> s = "x"
>>> s[1:2]
''
>>> s[1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

In some rare occasions this can be convenient/useful when you want to make a check and avoid the possibility of unhanded exception.

Perhaps also worth mentioning here: there is a more significant difference with bytestrings, for which slicing again returns substrings but subscription returns *ordinals*.

```
>>> b'xyz'[1]
121
>>> b'xyz'[1:2]
b'y'
```

Comment: I am concerning my answer with strings only (lists, dicts, etc are out of scope here)

Comment: Python `bytes` objects are definitely not the same thing as strings (at least not in Python 3)!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're working with valid indices, for string slicing there's no difference, because a single element of a string is still itself a string (i.e. there's no difference between a "character" and a string that's one character long).

```
>>> word = 'asdf'
>>> word[1:2]
's'
>>> word[1]
's'
```

For other slicable objects (e.g. a list) the two may not be equivalent:

```
>>> word = ['a', 's', 'd', 'f']
>>> word[1:2]
['s']
>>> word[1]
's'
```

Comment: There is a small difference. `''[1]` raises an `IndexError` while `''[1:2]` returns an empty string.

Comment: True; I'm assuming you're accessing a valid index (and also that the object is slicable in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

`word[1]` is different from word[1:2]. `word[1]` is returning the value of list item with index 1. But also word[1:2] is a list slice which returns the list in the position of 1.
example:

```
word = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(word[1])
#output: b
#but also
print(word[1:2])
#output: ['b']
```

Comment: *"...to slice **a string**"*

Comment: to slice the list. whatever it is a string or an integer

Comment: What? The slice applies to the *container*, not the *element*.